# .profile has statements to call .bashrc, but .bashrc not executed

Tags: bash, ubuntu, if-statement

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.  In my `$HOME/.profile`, it has

```
echo `date` ':.profile executed starts' >> /tmp/testtmp.txt
echo $BASH_VERSION >> /tmp/testtmp.txt
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
echo 'if 1 entered' >> /tmp/testtmp.txt
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    echo 'if 2 entered' >> /tmp/testtmp.txt
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
else
    echo 'if 1 not entered' >> /tmp/testtmp.txt
fi
```

Every time I login, it never even reaches the first `IF`.

The test file shows:

```
Sat Jan 14 05:15:57 EST 2017 :.profile executed starts

if 1 not entered
Sat Jan 14 05:15:57 EST 2017 :.profile executed ends
```

I echoed $BASH_VERSION, it shows `4.3.46(1)-release`. So if `if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]` is meant to check if that variable exists, (apparently yes), why is it not even reaching the first IF?

From the result, it looks like $BASH_VERSION is not generated until the first time I invoked terminal application.

As those IF statements in .profile are original, I don't understand if $BASH_VERSION is not generated when you login in, what is the purpose to have these statements originally.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it never reaches the first `if` statement? Also, is it `.profile` or `.bashrc` that is not being executed? Your title says one but the body says the other.

Comment: How did u call the .profile file? Using `source ~/.profile`? Also where did you echo the $BASH_VERSION

Comment: sorry guys.  I updated my question.

Comment: my `echo $BASH_VERSION` in .profile shows empty.  But when I do it manually in terminal, it gives me value.

Comment: I didn't call .profile manually.  It was called automatically when I login.

Comment: `.profile` can be used by any POSIX-compatible shell; `.bashrc` is specific to `bash`, and should not be sourced from `.profile`. Use `.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: looks like this is more like a ubuntu specifically lated question, not a coding question

Comment: I agree- someone on Ask Ubuntu might have more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

(This was getting overly long as a comment :) )

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/388014/642296) on Ask Ubuntu.  `.profile` is probably running under `sh`, not `bash`, so `BASH_VERSION` isn't set in `.profile`.

To test this, add

```
ps >> /tmp/testtmp.txt
```

to your `.profile`.  You will see the process name of the shell you're running under, which may be dash per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/87857/642296).

To see what your default shell is, `grep <whatever your username is> /etc/passwd` - you will see `/bin/<whatever>sh`.

If indeed `/bin/bash` is not set as your default shell, you can change it (per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/388027/642296)):

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash <whatever your username is>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Here's my test result. 
1.  my userid in `/etc/passwd` says it is using `/bin/bash`
2. `ps >> /tmp/testtmp.txt` shows me nothing related with sh or bash.

Comment: I read that post on askubuntu.  In his case, by chsh login shell from sh to bash, it resolved his issue.  But as my login shell is already bash, I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: I hardcoded running .bashrc into .profile.  The same as the post in askubuntu.  It cannot parse bash statements in .bashrc.